# How to clear history on logout in React-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-admin

I've a problem with react-admin when user logout. Steps:

1. Log in the app mydomain.com
2. The user goes to mydomain.com/users
3. The user push "logout button"
4. Now, the URL is mydomain.com/login
5. Log in the app with another user
6. Now, the URL is mydomain.com/users again....

I want to, once you have logged out, if you wants to log another time, the app must send you to home page (/) not the last page before you logged out.

It's possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to wipe the history; there is something wrong with your code.

Your main app routes that need auth should be protected, e.g. if there is no auth cookie or session users should get redirected to log in, for example.

When a user logs in, they should be directed to the base route of your app, e.g. www.yourdomain.com/

It's hard to know what wrong with out seeing your code, or what your using for routing but clearing history is not the right approach.

Comment: The react-admin the demo behaves the same: https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/login

Comment: Think about it from the user's point of view, how annoyed would you be if an app cleared your history.

Comment: The demo is excellent and if you want you can make your app go to where the user last was when you log in, or you can redirect them to home. I usually redirect the user to the root of the app on login, but that is because my dashboard is where updates are displayed.

Comment: can you tell me how I can do it in authProvider?

Comment: I have not used React-Admin my self so not 100% sure but a quick look tell me it uses React Router so you could the history hook to push the user to home.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has been bothering me for a while but never been forced to change it for me until recently. I'm not sure if you are using custom Login or Logout component, but if you do, what you need to do is quite simple without clearing the history(which I think it is unnecessary and potentially dangerous?).

This is what I did.

1. import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
2. in your Login or Logout component define, const history = useHistory();
3. when handling login or logout function of your own, push the main route.
   for example, login(auth).then(result => history.push('/'))
4. Done.

Frankly, I've tried on Login instead of Logout but if you are going to implement on Logout, make sure you put that code AFTER Logout component finishes rendering.